# confirmation tab does not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So i have created a form. Upon submitting that form, i created a confirmation tab so that the user can confirm his inputs. once the user confirms the inputs, the form will be submitted.

So i have added jquery to display the confirmation tab however, when i click the button to show the confirmation tab, the form just clears up and the confirmation tab is not seen... please find below the codes

HTML

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <fieldset class="tab-pane active" id="form_tab">
      <form id="poform" method="GET">
         <table>
               <tr>  
                    <th colspan="2"><div class="header_3">Pre-Order Form</div></th>
               </tr>
               <tr>  
                    <td><label>Account Number:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="accountnumber" id="accountnumber" value="" required/></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>  
                    <td><label>Trade:</label></td>
                    <span class="text_11">
                    <td><input type="radio" id="Buy" name="tradetype" class="tradetype" required value="Buy"/> Buy
                    <input type="radio" id="Sell" name="tradetype" class="tradetype" value="Sell"/> Sell </span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>  
                    <td><label>Metal:</label></td>
                    <span class="text_11">
                    <td><input type="radio" id="Steel" name="metal" class="metal" required value="Steel"/> Steel
                    <input type="radio" id="Iron" name="metal" class="metal" value="Iron"/> Iron </span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>  
                    <td class="select"><label>Amount:</label></td>
                    <td><select id="amount" name="amount">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <?php include_once "selectamount.php"?></td>
                    </select>
               </tr>
               <tr>  
                    <td class="select"><label>Date:</label></td>
                    <td><select id="date" name="date" id="date">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <?php include_once "selectdate.php"?></td>
                    </select>
               </tr> 
               <tr> 
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <button type="button" id="submit_btn">
                       <span class="chngetext">Check</span>
                    </button>
                    </td>
               </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="tab-pane" id="conf_tab">
    <table>
        <tr style="text-align:center">
            <th colspan="2"><div class="header_3">Pre-Order Ticket Details</div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align:left">
            <td><label>Account Number:</label></td>
            <td><mgin><span id="confirm_accountnumber"></span></mgin></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="text-align:left">
            <td><label>Trade Pre-Order:</label></td>
            <td><mgin><span id="confirm_tradetype"></span></mgin></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Amount:</label></td>
            <td><mgin><span id="confirm_amount"></span> 9999 Pooled Allocated <span id="confirm_metal"></span> Loco Singapore</mgin></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>On date:</label></td>
            <td><mgin><span id="confirm_date"></span></mgin></td>
        </tr>
            <td><label>Pre-Order Discount:</label></td>
            <td><mgin><span id="confirm_data"></span></mgin></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Pre-Order Deposit:</label></td>
            <td><mgin>SGD 5000.00</mgin></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Additional follow up order:</label></td>
            <td><mgin>New Sell Order to be given 2 days before purchase order date.</mgin></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="confirm_btn">Confirm Order</button></td>
        </tr>       
    </table>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_btn').click(function() {

    // Get the value of the field with 'firstname' id.
    var accountnumber = $('#accountnumber').val();
    var tradetype = $('input.tradetype:checked').val();
    var amount = $('#amount').val();
    var metal = $('input.metal:checked').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();
    var data = "<?php include 'retrievepremordisc.php'; ?>";

    $('#confirm_accountnumber').text(accountnumber);
    $('#confirm_tradetype').text(tradetype);
    $('#confirm_amount').text(amount);
    $('#confirm_metal').text(metal);
    $('#confirm_date').text(date);
    $('#confirm_data').text(data);

    // Hide form tab and show confirmation tab
    $('#form_tab').removeClass('active');
    $('#conf_tab').addClass('active');

  });
});
```

PHP file (retrievepremordisc.php)

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 

$form=$_GET;
$trade=$form['tradetype'];
$metal=$form['metal'];
$amount=$form['amount'];
$date=$form['date'];

$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT Discount FROM Contracts WHERE Trade='$trade' AND Metal='$metal' AND Amount='$amount' AND ExpiryDate='$date'");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
   echo $row['Discount']; 
} 
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: When you click in the submit button, the form performs a submit action, so the jQuery code doesn't execute. Change `<button type="submit" name="submit" id="check but">Check Premium</button>` to `<button type="button" name="submit" id="checkbut">Check Premium</button>`.

Comment: Or you can add inside the click function `$('#checkbut').click(function(e /* add e parameter to get the click event*/) {` - `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click in the submit button, the form performs a submit action, so the jQuery code doesn't execute.

Change

`<button type="submit" name="submit" id="checkbut">Check Premium</button>`

to

`<button type="button" name="submit" id="checkbut">Check Premium</button>`.

Other way is by using `event.preventDefault();`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#checkbut').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // This prevents the action of sending the form.

    // Get the value of the field with 'firstname' id.
    var accountnumber = $('#accountnumber').val();
    var tradetype = $('#tradetype').val();
    var amount = $('#amount').val();
    var metal = $('#metal').val();
    var date = $('#date').val();

    $('#confirm_accountnumber').text(accountnumber);
    $('#confirm_tradetype').text(tradetype);
    $('#confirm_amount').text(amount);
    $('#confirm_metal').text(metal);
    $('#confirm_date').text(date);

    // Hide form tab and show confirmation tab
    $('#form_tab').removeClass('active');
    $('#conf_tab').addClass('active');

  });
});
```

---

However:

Id selectors must be unique in the page. You have two buttons with same id. You need to rename properly with unique identifiers.

By the context of your html:

```
<div id="Sellbut" class="toHide" style="display:none"><button type="submit" name="submit" id="checkbut">Check Premium</button></div>
<div id="Buybut" class="toHide" style="display:none"><button type="submit" name="submit" id="checkbut">Check Discount</button></div>
```

These buttons seem perform different actions, so you'll need to rename it.

Comment: actually the two buttons with same IDs are for the same purpose. i have another Jquery which determines which one is shown cause i want to have the button display to be based on the radio button selection... '$(function() {
  $('.tradetype').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Buy') {$('#Buybut').show(); $('#Sellbut').hide();}
    if($(this).val() == 'Sell') {$('#Sellbut').show(); $('#Buybut').hide();} 
  });
});
'

Comment: i think because of this, the above code is also not working...any suggestions?

Comment: Please, can you update your question with all the code that you have? I can help you.

Comment: i have added the entire code above. Near the end of the html/php code there is a span "confirm_data"... this is from the jquery where i call forward a php file. I have also included the php file above which retrieves data from my database based on the input from the form in the first part of the html/php... however, when i click the button "check", this php file does not run --> currently i get <?php include 'retrievepremordisc.php'; ?> as the output.. is it possible to run the php in such a situation where i do not really submit the form?

Answer (score 1):

Use event.preventDefault(); in you click function.

Comment: That will work but it will be useful to the OP if you explained why it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Each id must be unique within the HTML document.  Both of your buttons use `id="checkbut"`, but the jQuery call `$('#checkbut')` will only refer to one of them (probably the first), and the other won't get a click handler at all.

Since it is not clearly defined how a browser should behave when there are 2 elements with the same id, that behavior could vary significantly between browsers.

You could change `id=` to `class=` the HTML, and the selector to `$(".checkbut")` to refer to the both at once.

Comment: actually the two buttons with same IDs are for the same purpose. i have another Jquery which determines which one is shown cause i want to have the button display to be based on the radio button selection... '$(function() { $('.tradetype').change(function() { if($(this).val() == 'Buy') {$('#Buybut').show(); $('#Sellbut').hide();} if($(this).val() == 'Sell') {$('#Sellbut').show(); $('#Buybut').hide();} }); });'

Comment: i think because of this, the above code is also not working...any suggestions?

Comment: Try logging/alerting how many elements are selected by `$('#checkbut')` if that only selects one, only one of your buttons will work.  Giving them both a common class and selecting by that should work better.